# ECharts - Click on radar's axis labels

Tags: echarts

I'm looking to set a click event on axis labels on ECharts's radar (version 4.4.0) : 
[image]

I tried 2 things already :

- Trying to use an existing event in the API documentation.

- Looking toward radar.axisLabel.formatter or radar.axisLabel.rich parameters to create a clickable element / button and create my own event.

Without any success just yet.

Is there a simple way to do what I want ?

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [docs](https://www.echartsjs.com/en/option.html#radar.triggerEvent), triggerEvent is set to *false* by default for radar charts.

To enable the clicking of the labels, enable the triggerEvent to the radar component:

```
radar: {
   name: {
      indicator: your_indicators,
      triggerEvent: true, <--- Set this to true
   },
}
```

Then make use of JS/jQuery click events to respond to each click event as follows:

```
$(function () {
    myChart.on('click', function(params) {
       if (params.name == 'Your Label') {
          console.log(params.name);
       }
    });
});
```

If you do happen to add line-breaks to your labels, remember to replace all line breaks and trim empty spaces within your click function:

```
var label = params.name.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").trim();
```

Comment: Close, `triggerEvent: true` has to be at the same level than the 'name' property.
But that was the solution ! Thank you very much.